# ViewController in Swift is zoomed in when I run it

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

When I run it they seemed to be zoomed in. There is no constraints and even if I try adding another viewController it is the same for all of them.

[What image Looks Like When I Run It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA3SP.png)

[What image should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQOJn.png)

Comment: You need to add constraints to tell Autolayout what to do

Answer (score 0):

You are not using autolayout correctly - try to set trailing property for every element and the autolayout will calculate width for actual width of device.

Small test: run in on iPad you should see more of textField - maybe the whole one.